# Heat Map of Spatial Data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, spatial, heatmap

Im am writing a Python Code. My dataset is composed of three columns, the firs two are the coordinates, and the third is a heat estimation

```
                   X              Y      heat
0      497935.000000  179719.000000  0.048428
1      497935.000000  179719.000000  0.029399
2      497935.000000  179719.000000  0.066734
3      497935.000000  179719.000000  0.065524
4      497935.000000  179719.000000  0.062458
5      497935.000000  179719.000000  0.032225
6      497935.000000  179719.000000  0.028557
7      497463.000000  179526.000000  0.000388
8      497899.000000  179305.000000  0.000733
9      497805.000000  179364.000000  0.000158
10     498264.000000  180349.000000  0.000036
11     498020.000000  179602.000000  0.003149
...              ...            ...       ...
```

I would like to plot the data in the XY plane, assigning a colour to each point with reflects its heat value. For the moment I tried with the command

> plt.scatter(df.X, df.Y)

[image]

but where every dot has a colour with depends on its heat, in Python. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck, thanks!

Comment: @plamut All I did is plt.plot(data.X,data.Y,'.b'), but the point was that I DONT know how to colour each data point/

Comment: Maybe pass the `color = data.heat` option? (not sure, but it seems pretty logical to me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-scatter):

> The keyword c may be given as the name of a column to provide colors for each point:

```
In [64]: df.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', c='c', s=50);
```

So what you need to do is to simply specify that the `heat` column contains the information about each point's color:

```
df.plot.scatter(x=data.X, y=data.Y, c=data.heat)
```

If you want to apply a custom color map, there is also the `cmap` parameter, allowing you to specify a different [color map](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap)

You can also read more about in in the docs for the [scatter()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) method.

Comment: Do you know how to make it colorful ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer - there is a `cmap` parameter, allowing you to customize the heatmap (applicable only if `c` is a list of numbers).