# Plot a heat graph with lat and long grouping by year

Tags: python, pandas, charts, heatmap, folium

I have a df of incident report information with a few columns. Among them, I have the column of year (year of the report information), latitude and longitude. This df has around 1.1 million lines as below

```
YEAR    LAT            LONG
2007    -23.54888115   -46.61859308
2007    -23.53578729   -46.76441089
2011    -23.60330318   -46.67685451
2018    -23.5403854    -46.3614019
```

I want to make a heat graph per year using the lat and long information but I have no idea how to iterate over the years and for each year plot the latitudes and longitudes.

```
map = folium.Map(location=[-23.5475, -46.63611])
ano = df_furtos['ANO_BO'].tolist()
lat = df_furtos['LATITUDE'].tolist()
lng = df_furtos['LONGITUDE'].tolist()
HeatMap(list(zip(lat, lng))).add_to(map)
```

I'm using Folium to plot the graph, but I know how to make the graph just by using lat and long.

However, I want that if I have a 10-year history of lat and long, I want to plot 10 graphs each with their respective latitudes and longitudes.

Can someone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: You should use `groupby()` to group your data by years.

Comment: May I know what is a heat graph? You mean the LAT and LONG are unique and can repeat themselves many times a year?

Comment: a heat graph would be a graph where the places where there are more "occurrences" are with stronger color tones, like red for example. In my case, lat and long are not unique, as they refer to car thefts

Comment: In that case, you would need some form of interpolation scheme since the lat, longs are unique. Isnt it?

Comment: lat and longs are unique but can be repeated. But I have my entire data set ready

Comment: Sorry that was stupid. Heatmap would have resolution and count unique values in that region. Isn't it?

Comment: That! I have these values. but I need to iterate over the list containing the year and values ​​and for each year plot the graph

Comment: I wonder you could only create a scatter plot but not heat map for this 2D data (lat, long). Heat map is possible only if there is third dimension. Isn't it? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264887/heat-map-of-spatial-data-in-python